# Things to ensure when deploy new laravel 5 project to VPS server

Tags: laravel-5, deployment

I have just finished my Laravel development (with some jquery / javascript) project and I am preparing to officially launch the website with vps servier. For the smooth running and security of the website, I only know how to handle some things in the .env file like blow:

Besides this configuration, are there any other things I have handle it before launching the website officially?

.env

```
APP_NAME=MyProject
APP_ENV=production
APP_KEY=base64:u93RlbQ5zcs.............
APP_DEBUG=false
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://mydomain

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=mydbname
DB_USERNAME=myuser
DB_PASSWORD=*******************

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=info@mydomain.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=*******************
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=SSL

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems OK, i have seen similar `.env` files running on various production servers.

Comment: Is there any other things I need to do beside the .env files?

Comment: Secure MySQL and Redis (no remote access), remove auth password for SSH (use SSH key only), install a firewall, program backups on your database every day and save it elsewhere. But most important: crash your VPS then rebuild it (then you will know what to do in case of crash).

Comment: What should I do with Redis? And do you recommend not use SSH key?

Comment: Without changing anything, redis is secure (so if you didn't change anything, it must be OK). About SSH Key, you should use SSH (and you should not use classic password). BTW I wrote a tutorial to install a Laravel production server months ago: https://github.com/rap2hpoutre/laravel-prod-server